# Separate apache VirtualHosts for ssl/non-ssl sites necessary?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I've got a site which allows for ssl and non-ssl browsing.

I've got two virtualhosts set up in Apache to handle the two scenarios, ie:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
...
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
...
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now, my annoyance is that the (rather large) configuration is duplicated in both the vhosts (the only difference being the added SSL parameters in the ssl-vhost), so when I want to change something, I need to do it in both. It also feels and looks sloppy.

Is there any way to merge the two configurations?

Many thanks.

Comment: different ports, setting up certificates etc are the reasons you need to have separate virtual hosts in your config.

Comment: If you set cookies / use session management, it's very hard to make the SSL requests properly secure without a lot of additional code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is needed as mentioned by @Hex in his comment.

However, you can take a shortcut and use the [`Include`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include) directive to not have the common configuration redundant, like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ...
    include conf/common_rule.conf
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ... #SSL rules
    include conf/common_rule.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

<sup>Stolen from the pretty much similar question ["Do I have to duplicate the Virtualhost directives for port 80 and 443?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679383/do-i-have-to-duplicate-the-virtualhost-directives-for-port-80-and-443).</sup>